# Access 2013: I am trying to return today's date when a yes/no fields is marked as "Yes"

Tags: date, iif

I am trying to return today's date in a date field when another field is marked as "Yes". I tried the following expression but to no avail. I have limited experience with expressions and greatly appreciate any guidance. If the field does not have a "Yes" the date field can be blank. I cannot set the default to "No" for the Approved field.

Approved Date: IIf([Approved]=True,Today(),Null)

If I set the date, it will work but the date is dynamic so this is not really helpful. 
Approved Date: IIf([Approved]=True,5/1/2016,Null)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I spent a little time looking at how to do this with an expression. The answer is you can't, at least not without a helper function. So, my hybrid solution is:

1) Create a function in a standard module:

```
Public Function SetControlValue( _
    ByVal ctlControl As Access.Control, _
    ByVal varValue As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal varTest As Variant = True)
        If (varTest) Then
            ctlControl.Value = varValue
        End If
End Function
```

2) In the `AfterUpdate` event for the Approved checkbox, enter:

```
=SetControlValue([ApprovedDate],Date(),([Approved]=True) AND (IsNull([ApprovedDate])))
```

This approach saves you from making a class module under the form. And you can keep all such code in a common module, so you can build a library of such functions for other forms.

---

(old answer 2)

Based on your answers, what you can do is add an `AfterUpdate` event to the Approved control, which does something like:

```
Private Sub Approved_AfterUpdate() 
    If (Approved.Value = True) And IsNull(ApprovedDate.Value) Then 
        ApprovedDate.Value = Date()
    End If
End Sub
```

This will set the approved date once, when the approved checkbox is first checked. If you need different behavior, this can easily be modified.

---

(old answer 1)

I think you have it backwards. 
When [Approved] is set to True, set [ApprovedDate] = Today(). That way, it is saved to the table, and you have a permanent record of when it was approved.

Comment: I need the Approved Date to populate based on Approved = Yes and am looking for an expression that will achieve that.

Comment: What you are saying is very close to what I am saying. My questions are:  1) Do you want to save the Approved Date when Approved is first set to Yes, or do you just want it to display Today(), regardless of when it was approved?  2) Are you doing this in a Form or Query?  Thanks.

Comment: 1. I want the Approved Date to display the date that Approved was first set to "Yes". 2. I am doing this in Form.

Comment: Kismert: Thank you for your response. I added this in the Properties as Code for the Approved field but it did not work. I get a '424' error. Should the code reference a different property or object? Is there anyway to get this to work in the expression builder? I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Does it matter that the Approved field is Yes/No checkbox?

Comment: Error 424 is 'Object required'. Without looking at your code, you made some basic error. Make sure your control names are spelled correctly. See my revised answer for another approach.

Comment: In both answers, names were spelled correctly (I copied the code directly from what you provided and also entered it) but neither the initial approach or revised approach worked. In the revised answer, I added the function by clicking on the module icon and then added the AfterUpdate as an expression but it did not work. I got an an error about "The object doesn't contain Automation object 'Approved Date'.

Comment: In my examples, I am assuming you have a controls named `Approved`, and another named `ApprovedDate`. Perhaps your control is named `Approved Date` (the space is significant). Rename the control so it matches the code, and it should work.

Comment: I did have a space in Approved Date. Removing the space, got rid of the error but now it updates the ApprovedDate field with today's date regardless if there is a check in the checkbox in the Approved field. It just adds the date each time I start entering a new record. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so I tested my latest suggestion using the `SetControlValue` function, and it works for me. Please make sure the `=SetControlValue([ApprovedDate],Date(),([Approved]=True) AND (IsNull([ApprovedDate])))` expression is in the `Approved` checkbox's `AfterUpdate` event.

Comment: So, I just deleted everything and started from scratch and it worked. I apologize for the back and forth. I am thinking maybe a previous iteration got saved and that is why every record was populating with the date regardless of the check for Approved. I really appreciate all of your help. Thank you.